# CSS recipe to fill the empty space on the body of printable page with Horizontal Lines

Tags: css

I am extracting project details from a database and composing a dynamic HTML page for printing with those project details at the top.  The intention for the page is to record information regarding the project in a team, or other, meeting and I would like to have lines appear in the space after the project details.

What combination of CSS pseudo tags or CSS functions could I use to fill the empty body of the page with horizontal lines?

Comment: i can't get you man, could just include an image or a fiddle with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the css function repeating-linear-gradient in an after psuedo tag.

Assuming the project details is in an element with the class called project_details the CSS would contain the following:

```
.project_details::after {
  content:          '';
  display:          block;
  width:            100%;
  height:           29cm;
  background:       repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,blue 0px, white 1px,white 30px);
}
```

The content attribute is required and is an empty string to coerce the browser into using the selector.  If the content property is not specified then the "after" selector is ignored by the browser.

The block, display and width are required to let the browser know the physical size of the space to be filled.  In the solution provided the width is 100% of the page width while the height is roughly the height of an A4 size sheet of paper.

The background is a repeating linear gradient with a single 1 pixel width blue line and a 29px whitespace.  0deg represents a horizontal gradient.  The gradient goes from blue to white for the first pixel (pixel 0) and from white to white from pixel 1 up to the 30th pixel and repeats.

The are a couple of potential pitfalls:

1. The print rendering of the browser might require a line width to be great than 1px to ensure all lines are printed.
2. The print dialogue may default to "background graphics" flagged off and will need to be switch to on for the lines to be visible.